# Storyboard segue crash and UINavigationController best practices

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm using a storyboard based setup and have a UINavigationController that tracks a set of UIViewControllers as they do... i have a single main UIViewController that acts as a "home screen' and all activities and tasks branch off from there.

As things stand, under certain scenarios I pop to the root view controller and some scenarios I actually have a segue that points back to that root "home screen" view controller.

I've been seeing some crashes pop up when i land back on the home view controller and then go to segue away from there again... the error is

```
Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'xxx'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.
```

...could this occur because of the cyclical nature of my storyboard? is it okay that I have these segues going back to the home view controller? does this create another instance of the home view controller? should i just always pop to root instead?

Comment: I hope this will helps u and resolve your issue 

[Unwind Segue][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-to-use-them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not OK to "go back" to any controller with a segue (other than an unwind) because, yes, it does create a new instance. If you want to go back you have to use an unwind segue, or popToRootViewController (or any of the other pop methods) in a navigation controller based app.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. in retrospect it seems obvious but for whatever reason i've gotten this far with these bad practices in place... :-)